# Birthday Paradox: does it count if people are born in the same year?

Tags: probability, birthday-paradox

Does the [birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) change if we only take people from the same year (e.g. a classroom)?

Intuitively I think it does, because you have more probabilities to have two people born in different years on the same day and month than to have them on the exactly same date. But with only intuition and no demonstration, this is a weak argument.

Comment: Count for what? Please tell us what kind of problem you are dealing with.

Comment: I don't think it matters, as long as the probability of being born on a specific date does not change over time.

Comment: The birthday problem just refers to day of year.

Answer (score 4):

It actually does not. The birthday "problem" as usually stated (there's actually no problem...) only relies on days of the year (and an independence assumption).

Most of the time intuition in statistics must be double-checked by calculation, in here the calculation (no matter how you do it), does not use the year, hence the problem is independent from the year.